# Attach_file with unicode filenames show up as "noname"

Tags: python, django, email

I have an issue with attached files containing unicode chars (mainly æ, ø and å) showing up as "noname" in the e-mail. The attached files comes from FileFields, so they are attached from the system.

Here is part of the message function:

```
msg = mail.EmailMessage()
msg.subject = u"%s" % message.subject
msg.from_email = "%s <%s>" % (message.author_name, message.author_email)
msg.content_subtype = "html"
msg.body = render_to_string("core/send_message_all.html", locals())
message_to = re.split(", |,", message.receiver)
if message.file1:
    msg.attach_file(message.file1.file.path)
msg.send(fail_silently=False)
```

I'm using Django 1.4.5. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I've thought about slugifying the filenames on upload, but then I would also have to slugify the existing files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with another approach. I used attach() instead of attach_file() and changed the filename on the attachment only.

in document model:

```
def filename(self):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', os.path.basename(self.file.name)).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

In views.py:

```
file_1 = open(message.file1.file.path)
msg.attach(message.file1.filename(), file_1.read(), message.file1.content_type)
```

The reason for "message.file1" is because it's a ForeignKey

Sorry for the inconvenience :-)